# How to get equation or value on matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to get equation or value on matplotlib plot

I make plot
`x : range(5)` ,

```
 y = [ 5 , 20 , 1 , 7 ,9 ]
```

matplotlib make a plot like under the picture.

And then, I want to get the value that is between 20 and 1

I guess matplotlib fit anything model, and make y_hat and plotting y_hats

so, who is teaching me, how to get equation of access equation or value

-- if you don't understand my text, reference the picture.
I think you will understand what I want to do.

[image]

Comment: If you run this in a terminal, the window it brings up has a subwindow that shows the x and y values under the cursor.  Images in your notebook are static.

Comment: Is there any chance, do you know api that get value or equation ?

Comment: There is no API.  If you do this in a notebook, that's just an image.  Now, each of your segments is linear, and it's easy to compute the equation for each segment.  Lines are always `y=mx+b`; for that segment, it would be `y = -19x + 39`.

Answer (score 0):

It will be very easy to use the NumPy interp function. Just giving the x-positions and original X,Y array. np.interp will return the corresponding y-values (Linear interpolation).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = range(5)
y =  [ 5 , 20 , 1 , 7 ,9 ]

xvals = np.linspace(1, 2, 10)
yinterp = np.interp(xvals, x, y)
plt.plot(x, y, '-o',label="org data")

plt.plot(xvals, yinterp, 'x',label="interp data")
plt.legend()
plt.savefig("interp.png")
plt.show()
```

[image: output figure]